# What is the smallest amounts of bytes I can extract from an encrypted RAR file and how can I extract it and verify using CRC32

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have a school project in which I must use brute-force attack to recover the password of an encrypted RAR file. It is obvious that using brute-force on AES256 encryption system is not very useful but the aim of the homework is learning about brute-force so cracking speed is not important. Dictionary attack and known plain text attack is not permitted by the teacher. And I've learned from the posts I've read in this website that these methods are not much better at cracking passwords when it comes to AES either.

From studying various RAR extracting libraries including the official winRAR source code (found in rarlab.com) and the source code of a populer password cracking software called John the Ripper, I realized that finding the hashed key from the RAR file is impossible (This topic was discussed in another question on this website too) .

So the only actual way to actually try brute-force attack on an encrypted RAR file is extracting the archive with the guessed password and calculating CRC32 checksum to see if the files are extracted correctly.

From a RAR-unlocker source code I found the polynomial of CRC32 which is :

```
X^32+X^26+X^23+X^22+X^16+X^12+X^11+X^10+X^8+X^7+X^5+X^4+X^2+X^1+X^0
```

The source code is here: https://github.com/RaMMicHaeL/RAR-Unlocker/blob/master/crc32.cpp

Now my problem is, even though I said at the beginning that cracking speed is not very important, I can't afford to extract to whole archive and calculate CRC32 for every guess. For a big file this could mean minutes for every single try.

So I figured that if I could extract only a small part of the archive(let's say, a couple of bytes) with my guessed key and calculate the CRC32 checksum to see if the files are extracted correctly, I can use the same key to extract the whole file too.

This is where I am right now. I'm **very** new to cryptography so I am not %100 sure what I proposed above is possible at all. If it is, what is the smallest amount of bytes I can extract from the archive that can be used for checksum? How can I extract my selected amount of bytes from the archive?

Thanks.

Comment: You have extract exactly the bytes that are included in the CRC calculation, no more and no less.

Comment: So I have to extract 32 bit (or 4 byte) information. Is extracting exactly the first 4 byte of RAR archive possible at all?

Comment: You're the RAR expert, not me. The CRC is calculated over some part of the archive, I don't know what that is. But whatever it is, you must extract and decrypt that *and* the CRC, then recompute the CRC over the just-decrypted plaintext and compare it to the recovered CRC. If they are the same you *might* have the correct key, if they are different you definitely *do not* have the correct key.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks for your reply.